# Can VBA delete named ranges based on RefersTo value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, named-ranges

I'm cleaning up a bloated Excel workbook and am trying to bulk delete named ranges that are referring to workbooks on someones 'C' drive. There are a lot of them. And they are not being used in this Workbook.

> 'C:\blahblah\...\...\...\...\...\[WorkBookName.xls]Sheet1'!$E$28

The code below helped me delete named ranges where their name contains 'icon' (for example).

However, I really need to delete the range when it contains a path as shown above. Bearing in mind that the Workbook or Sheet name could also change, *but the drive remains the same.*

```
Sub deleteNamedRangesSpecific()
For Each NR In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If NR.NameLocal Like "*" & "icon" & "*" Then NR.delete
Next
End Sub
```

Any ideas how to delete according to the range itself, not the name of the range?

Thanks.

Mike.

Comment: `If ... Then Range(nr).ClearContents`?  Or `.Delete` if you want to remove the cells/rows

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass the `NR.RefersTo` variant to a string type variable so you can use the `Like` function.

This code works for me.  Obviously edit `$E$28` to suit.

```
Option Explicit
Sub deleteNamedRangesSpecific()
    Dim NR As Name
    Dim compare_string As String
    For Each NR In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        compare_string = NR.RefersTo
        If compare_string Like "*" & "$E$28" & "*" Then NR.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you and welcome to Superuser